# :hover wont work on Navbar if I move the position of a <div> to center. Why?

Tags: html, css, hover, navbar

The hover works fine with this code but when I change the 'top' from 50% to something below 45%, the hover on the navbar will stop working. I want to center the h1 text with the two buttons, but I don't know how without disabling the hover on the navbar.

```css
.main-nav li:hover {
    background-color: hsla(180,50%,50%,0.28);
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
.una{
    width: 1200px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.gitna {
    position: absolute;
    Top: 50%;
    Left: 50%;
    Transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.btn:hover {
    background-color: darkslateblue;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
 <div>
 <div class="row">
            <ul class="main-nav">
                <li><a href=""> HOME </a></li>
                <li><a href=""> ABOUT </a></li>
                <li><a href=""> PHOTOGRAPHY </a></li>
                <li><a href=""> ORGANIZER </a></li>
                <li><a href=""> CONTACT </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="una gitna">
            <h1>Are you Ready?</h1>

            <div class="button">
                <a href="" class="btn btn-one">Explore</a>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-two">Other Websites</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Please let me know if I need to edit out more information of my css.

Comment: @JakubASuplicki Thank you for introducing me to flexbox! The writings are now centered using flex box. Thank you so much! :))

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

Doing it that way you will have less trouble positioning your elements and you will also avoid unexpected behavior. Additionally, you will achieve responsiveness out of the box.

Additionally, I used [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) on your `.main-nav` to demonstrate how you could easily make a decent looking navbar as well as `buttons`.

Have a look at my example.

```css
.main-nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.main-nav li:hover {
    background-color: hsla(180,50%,50%,0.28);
}
.main-nav li { 
    list-style: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.una{
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.gitna {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.button {
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.btn{
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.btn:hover {
    background-color: darkslateblue;
}
```

```html
       <div class="row">
            <ul class="main-nav">
                <li><a href=""> HOME </a></li>
                <li><a href=""> ABOUT </a></li>
                <li><a href=""> PHOTOGRAPHY </a></li>
                <li><a href=""> ORGANIZER </a></li>
                <li><a href=""> CONTACT </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="una gitna">
            <h1>Are you Ready?</h1>

            <div class="button">
                <a href="" class="btn btn-one">Explore</a>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-two">Other Websites</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: if you remove the transition out of `li:hover` and put this in `.main-nav li { transition: all 0.5s ease-in;}` it would transition smoothly even when you hover away

Comment: That is correct. However, I have not focused on the animation effect but the positioning of the elements which seemed to be the issue. Nevertheless, I edited the answer and added changes in order to achieve smoother transition as you mentioned @Ifaruki for both `buttons` and `li`.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything right just remove the `css` property `width:1200px` and it will work.

```css
.main-nav li:hover {
  background-color: hsla(180, 50%, 50%, 0.28);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

.una {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.gitna {
  position: absolute;
  Top: 50%;
  Left: 50%;
  Transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <ul class="main-nav">
    <li><a href=""> HOME </a></li>
    <li><a href=""> ABOUT </a></li>
    <li><a href=""> PHOTOGRAPHY </a></li>
    <li><a href=""> ORGANIZER </a></li>
    <li><a href=""> CONTACT </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="una gitna">
  <h1>Are you Ready?</h1>

  <div class="button">
    <a href="" class="btn btn-one">Explore</a>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-two">Other Websites</a>
  </div>
</div>
```